# How to merge two array and sum the value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my array

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
        array(3) {
        ["product"]=>
        string(14) "apple"
        ["quantity"]=>
        int(1)
        ["color"]=>
        string(5) "red"
    }
    [1]=>
        array(3) {
        ["quantity"]=>
        int(1)
        ["color"]=>
        string(6) "red"
        ["product"]=>
        string(17) "berry"
    }
    [2]=>
        array(3) {
        ["quantity"]=>
        int(5)
        ["color"]=>
        string(6) "green"
        ["product"]=>
        string(14) "apple"
    }
    [3]=>
        array(3) {
        ["quantity"]=>
        int(5)
        ["color"]=>
        string(6) "red"
        ["product"]=>
        string(14) "apple"
    }
    [4]=>
        array(3) {
        ["quantity"]=>
        int(4)
        ["color"]=>
        string(5) "red"
        ["product"]=>
        string(14) "apple"
    }
}
```

I want to sum the quantity if they are sample product and same quantity.
Red Apple x 1 and Red apple x 4 and Red Apple x 5 will be merged to Red Apple x 10 , But Green Apple will keep.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You say "if they are the same product and same _quantity_", but your example reflects same product and same color....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to combine that data.

```
$data = [
    ['product' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red',   'quantity' => 1],
    ['product' => 'berry', 'color' => 'red',   'quantity' => 1],
    ['product' => 'apple', 'color' => 'green', 'quantity' => 5],
    ['product' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red',   'quantity' => 5],
    ['product' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red',   'quantity' => 4],
];

$result = array_values(array_reduce($data, function($map, $item) {
    $key = "{$item['product']}_{$item['color']}";
    if (!isset($map[$key])) { // first occurence
        $map[$key] = $item;
    } else { // next occurence - just increment quantity 
        $map[$key]['quantity'] += $item['quantity'];
    }
    return $map;
}, []));

foreach ($result as $item) echo json_encode($item), PHP_EOL;
```

> ```
> {"product":"apple","color":"red","quantity":10}
> {"product":"berry","color":"red","quantity":1}
> {"product":"apple","color":"green","quantity":5}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your products are in an array like `$products`

```
$products = array( array('quantity' => 5, 'color' => 'red', 'product' => 'apple'), .. );
$summed = array();
for($i=0,$count=count($products);$i<$count;$i++) 
    if (!isset($summed[$products[$i]['product'].$products[$i]['color']])) {
        $summed[$products[$i]['product'].$products[$i]['color']] = $products[$i];
    } else $summed[$products[$i]['product'].$products[$i]['color']]['quantity'] += $products[$i]['quantity'];
```

now `$summed` has all your products ready. You can either ditch the keys with [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) or you can keep using it as it is.

Answer (score -3):

```
var $ret  = array();
foreach ($array as $value){
  foreach ($ret as &$v){
      if ($value['color'] == $v['color'] && $value['product'] == $v['product']){
          $v['quantity'] += $value['quantity'];
          $i = true;
      }
  }
   if(!$i){
      array_push($ret,$value);
  }
  unset($i);
}
```

Comment: You are pushing every value in the original array into a new one. The items in the array should reduce. I.e.: If a red apple is already in `$ret` then there is no reason to call `array_push` on it.

Comment: I am sorry ,  it is my fault

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @31piy Thanks for your reminding. I will correct it next time